# Разбор файла в текстовом формате с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Пишу на Perl. Значит есть текстовый файл, конец файла выглядит так:
два перевода строки, текст, два перевода строки, точка

Мне надо выцепить этот текст, но почему-то вроде бы банальное регулярное выражение `//n/n([/w/r/n]+)/n/n/./` не работает. Где я допустил ошибку при составлении регулярного выражения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
/^(\r?\n){2}(.+)(\r?\n){2}\./
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что должно быть не `/n`, а `\n`.